# What are these seeds from China, that are supposed to grow tea?

Tags: identification, seeds

[image: random seeds that someone must have mixed up when packaging, purchased through amazon, from a farm in china]

I bought these seeds online thinking they were supposed to grow tea. The site I used said they came from a farm in China. They look random and strange to me. They remind me of a cereal I used to eat, called Honey Nut, which had a frog on the box.

They look like they were once good quality, but some have broken up. I'm scared to plant them yet, until I know what they are.

Comment: When you say 'tea' seeds, what kind of tea?

Comment: Welcome! Those are interesting looking seeds! I used to eat that cereal! Would you tell us a few more things? Where do you live? Did the seller say they were supposed to grow a type of tea plant, or is it an herb you can use to make tea?  Do they smell, either good or bad?  Are they soft and squishy, or hard? Did anyt other seeds come with them? Anything more you can think of will be really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Chinese sites have often a problem with translation: they uses Google Translator or similar services, and the outcome often is very "interesting". Consider also that such translations lacks context (product name is not part of a long text), and missing species in English speaking world. It could be interesting, if you ask in the Chinese language sister site: maybe you will get some hints why they used the word "tea".

Comment: It is certainly not regular tea (camellia sinensis). Its seeds are spherical smooth nuts.